# Spring application stuck in start

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem since I export and import a spring project, and it is that now it takes more than 70 seconds to start. Get stuck in Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories ...

This is the log of the console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)

2021-01-19 21:00:48.994  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] com.practica.PracticaFinalApplication    : Starting PracticaFinalApplication on DESKTOP-BG6SBT4 with PID 15368 (D:\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.0.RELEASE\PRACTICA_FINAL\target\classes started by dani_ in D:\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.0.RELEASE\PRACTICA_FINAL)
2021-01-19 21:00:48.998  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] com.practica.PracticaFinalApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-19 21:00:49.051  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\dani_\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\jdbc\ojdbc8\19.3.0.0\ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/dani_/.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/19.3.0.0/oraclepki.jar
2021-01-19 21:00:49.051  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\dani_\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\security\oraclepki\19.3.0.0\oraclepki-19.3.0.0.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/dani_/.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/security/oraclepki/19.3.0.0/osdt_core.jar,file:/C:/Users/dani_/.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/security/oraclepki/19.3.0.0/osdt_cert.jar,file:/C:/Users/dani_/.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/security/oraclepki/oracle.osdt/osdt_core.jar,file:/C:/Users/dani_/.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/security/oraclepki/oracle.osdt/osdt_cert.jar
2021-01-19 21:00:49.052  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-01-19 21:00:49.052  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-01-19 21:00:49.767  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2021-01-19 21:00:49.848  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 75ms. Found 6 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-01-19 21:00:50.143  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5974c00c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-01-19 21:00:50.203  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2021-01-19 21:00:50.575  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8085 (http)
2021-01-19 21:00:50.586  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-19 21:00:50.587  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
2021-01-19 21:00:50.709  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-01-19 21:00:50.710  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1658 ms
2021-01-19 21:00:50.967  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-19 21:00:51.007  INFO 15368 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-01-19 21:00:51.055  INFO 15368 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.21.Final
2021-01-19 21:00:51.101  WARN 15368 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-01-19 21:00:51.160  INFO 15368 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2021-01-19 21:00:51.267  INFO 15368 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-01-19 21:00:51.313  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5548d944, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@52db2e9a, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2682a673, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@384244c7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@60a9bf00, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@14f3c976, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@14a70864, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@9aabdd5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@61618c62, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1e6efa12, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@72c01891, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@43f59fcf]
2021-01-19 21:00:51.534  INFO 15368 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-01-19 21:00:51.551  INFO 15368 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
2021-01-19 21:00:51.756  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-01-19 21:00:51.825  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8085 (http) with context path ''
2021-01-19 21:00:51.828  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2021-01-19 21:02:03.729  WARN 15368 --- [         task-1] o.h.b.i.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl    : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name sequence
2021-01-19 21:02:03.741  WARN 15368 --- [         task-1] o.h.b.i.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl    : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name sequence
2021-01-19 21:02:03.744  WARN 15368 --- [         task-1] o.h.b.i.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl    : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name sequence
2021-01-19 21:02:04.203  INFO 15368 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-01-19 21:02:04.211  INFO 15368 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-01-19 21:02:04.639  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2021-01-19 21:02:04.647  INFO 15368 --- [  restartedMain] com.practica.PracticaFinalApplication    : Started PracticaFinalApplication in 76.038 seconds (JVM running for 77.006)
```

And this is the pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.4.RELEASE
 

com.practica
PRACTICA_FINAL
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
war
PRACTICA_FINAL
Practica

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a minimum amount of code and share this code here?

Comment: Is everything ok with your database connection? Is your DB in the same Host?

Comment: @Armin Yes, the database is on the same host and works correctly, because when the application starts everything works fine

Comment: @dan1st what do you mean with a minimum amount of code?

Comment: I think the pom.xml is not sufficient to reproduce it. Can you try to create an example project with the minmum amount of code possible to reproduce this problem? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details.

Answer (score 1):

In case it works for someone, I found the solution. I just had to add these two lines in my properties file and I went from starting in 70 seconds to starting in 4 seconds

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```